# rig not working after setting parent there is not mesh movement

Tags: rigging

hello i have a problem im doing a excersise for a class i had to deliver today

the problem is

the bones are not getting snapped to the mesh, when i go to pose mode the bones will move alone without the mesh

the mesh is simple is just 3 bones but is not working

what i am doing wrong?

rigging tutorial in less than 10 minutes:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DDeB4tDVCGY

this one i following it

blend file with bone mesh

https://workupload.com/file/ff7GehuKme6

i am using riggify

i am using blender LTS 3 69

Comment: Hello, I don't see any armature in your file, also the topology is pretty bad, you should first model an object rather low-poly and with a good topology

Comment: im sorry i did an error, uploaded wrong file

Comment: i know i did not retopologized it im not skilled for now on it, im just tryharding cause have to deliver in 1 hour

Comment: here is the link with the correct rig https://workupload.com/file/ff7GehuKme6

Comment: You need to select all in Edit mode and M > Merge by Distance but it will still be very bad

Comment: i have a idea, i can blow the wings and them start again in a modular way, with the desired pose, right?

Comment: because i selected all the mesh pressed m merged by distance and nothing happpened screenshoot here https://prnt.sc/OYElfMKey9lD

Comment: The topology is terrible as @moonboots says but merging by distance does indeed remove around 5400 vertices. Then unparenting the rig, deleting the modifier and Ctrl-P > Parent > With Automatic Weights does actually work although it took almost 30 seconds to complete the parenting here! It also parents part of the other side of your model which moves with the bone. - Not ideal!

Comment: will try, will come back with answers

Comment: omg the result is horrible D:!

Comment: how can i solve this ? https://prnt.sc/pRkR7STl6UQK screenshot

Comment: I don't think you can with your model and rig to be honest!

Comment: thanks will close this thread and try other workaround